# Failed loading config.ts due to import protractor

Tags: node.js, typescript, selenium, protractor, automated-tests

I am trying to start a new protractor project to test an angular site. I installed node.js, typescript, protractor globally and jasmine. I go to the project folder and do `webdriver-manager update`. Then I do `webdriver-manager start`. I also build the config.ts using `tsc config.ts`. Everything works fine until i try `protractor config.ts`. Here i will provide my config.ts and my package.json.

```
{
"name": "protractortests",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Automated tests for a game platform",
"main": "index.js",
"dependencies": {
  "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.12",
  "@types/node": "^12.0.2",
  "jasmine": "^3.4.0",
  "protractor": "^5.4.2"
},
"devDependencies": {},
"scripts": {
  "test": "protractor config.ts"
}
```

and my config.ts:

```
import { ProtractorBrowser, Config } from "protractor";
    export let config: Config = {
      seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
      capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
        },

      framework: 'jasmine',
      specs: ['./FirstSpec.ts'],
      jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 90000
      },
      onPrepare: () => {
       let globals = require('protractor/built');
       let browser = globals.browser;
       browser.manage().window().maximize();
       browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
     }
    }
```

```
E/configParser - Error code: 105
[11:40:53] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading configuration file config.ts
[11:40:53] E/configParser - C:\Users\Victor\Documents\ProtractorTests\config.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { ProtractorBrowser, Config } from "protractor";
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Comment: Try removing `import { ProtractorBrowser, Config } from "protractor";` These imports happen automatically when Protractor initializes

Comment: cant remove it, because its later used in the export config: Config

Comment: Oh my mistake, the import may be required when using typescript [based on this example](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.4.1/exampleTypescript/conf.ts). I would remove `ProtractorBrowser` however as that does not seem to be required

Comment: but still the same error :(

Comment: Are you transpiling your code using `npm run tsc` before trying to execute? If not give that a try

Comment: im doing tsc config.ts and then i do protractor config.ts but the problem persists

Comment: The reason is when you pass this config as it is to protractor it won't be able to understand as it's in typescript. Try to pass the js file which is the output of tsc.

Comment: As Yash suggested, you are getting this error because protractor is expecting a `.js` file, not a `.ts`. After compiling, try `protractor conf.js`

Answer (score 1):

By referring to example at link https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/5.4.1/exampleTypescript

You don't need to import ProtractorBrowser. You can work with browser directly with object Browser.

Answer (score 0):

Commenters pointed out that you can't give Protractor a config file in native Typescript, and need to compile it to `config.js` then pass that.  There's really no point in writing the file in Typescript at all, it just adds an extra step that provides no value to you.  If you want editor autocomplete, you can decorate your JS with type annotations:

```js
const { join } = require("path");
const { register } = require("ts-node");

const { SpecReporter, StacktraceOption } = require("jasmine-spec-reporter");


/** @type {import("protractor").Config} */
const config = {
    directConnect: true,
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:8080",
    framework: "jasmine",
    noGlobals: true,
    specs: [ "./src/**/*.e2e.ts" ],
    onPrepare() {
        register({
            project: join(__dirname, "./tsconfig.json")
        });
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
            spec: {
                displayStacktrace: StacktraceOption.PRETTY
            }
        }));
    }
};

module.exports = { config };
```

I adapted my config from [this excellent example](https://github.com/coryrylan/ng-pokedex/tree/master/e2e).