# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module when debugging Protractor Test in Visual Studio code

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, protractor, vscode-debugger

I am trying to setup my protractor to do debugging using VS Code. And I'm following the steps on this [page](https://medium.com/@ganeshsirsi/how-to-debug-protractor-tests-in-visual-studio-code-e945fc971a74).

However, I came up with this error/issue when running F5.

**ERROR**

```
E/configParser - protractor.config.ts:1
import { Config, browser } from 'protractor';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
```

---

### Code

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "types": ["jasmine", "node"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "mapRoot": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{

    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\Protractor\\node_modules\\protractor\\bin\\protractor",
            "args":[
                "${workspaceFolder}\\Protractor\\protractor.config.ts"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - Protractor/tsconfig.json",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/Protractor/dist/out-tsc/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**protractor.config.ts**

```
import { Config, browser } from 'protractor';
let BeautifulReporter:any, SpecReporter:any;

export let config: Config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    baseUrl: "",
    exclude: ['node_modules/**/*spec.js'],
    directConnect : true,

    params : {
        //Insert needed params
    },

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        // Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 270000,
        // onComplete will be called just before the driver quits.
        onComplete: null,
        // If true, display spec names.
        isVerbose: true,
        // If true, print colors to the terminal.
        showColors: true,
        // If true, include stack traces in failures.
        includeStackTrace: true,
        //If you set it to true it would not fail the whole test run, but it would show errors in a real time - immediately after happening
        realtimeFailure: true,
        print:()=>{}
    },

    //This capabilities is used for multiple browser testing
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'platform': 'ANY',
        'version': 'ANY',
        'chromeOptions': {
            // disable "chrome is being controlled by automated software"
            "excludeSwitches": [ "enable-automation" ],
            "useAutomationExtension": false,
            'args': ['disable-infobars=true', "--log-level=3", "--headless", "--window-size=1366x768"],
            w3c: false,
            prefs: {
                download : {
                    //'prompt_for_download': false,
                    //All downloading file will get downloaded at below location in folder fileDownload
                    'default_directory': __dirname + '\\downloadedfile'
                },
                'credentials_enable_service': false
            }
        }
    },

    beforeLaunch: () =>{
        
        require('ts-node').register({
            project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.json')
          });
    
        BeautifulReporter = require('protractor-beautiful-reporter');
        SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;
        BeautifulReporter = new BeautifulReporter({
            baseDirectory: 'reports/beautiful'
            , clientDefaults: {
                showTotalDurationIn: "belowHeader",
                totalDurationFormat: "hms",

                columnSettings: {
                    displayTime: true,
                    displayBrowser: false,
                    displaySessionId: false,
                    displayOS: false,
                    //inlineScreenshots:false
                }
            },
            preserveDirectory: false,
            takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
            jsonsSubfolder: 'jsons',
            screenshotsSubfolder: 'images',
            docName: 'test.html',
            docTitle: 'test'
        });
         
    },

    onPrepare: () => {
        let globals:any = global;
        globals.dvr = browser.driver;
        globals.EC = browser.ExpectedConditions;
        globals.baseDir = __dirname;
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(125000);
        //Clean up existing downloaded file in folder downloadedfile
        const fsExtra = require('fs-extra');
        fsExtra.emptyDirSync(__dirname + "/downloadedfile");

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(BeautifulReporter.getJasmine2Reporter());
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
            spec: {displayStacktrace: true}
        }));
        
    },


    afterLaunch: () => {}

};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "protractor",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/oracledb": "^5.1.0",
    "jasmine-custom-message": "^0.8.2",
    "jasmine2-custom-message": "^0.9.3",
    "runtypes": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/node": "^14.11.2",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "date-and-time": "^0.14.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "latest-version": "^3.1.0",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.4",
    "minimist": "^1.2.5",
    "oracledb": "^4.2.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "protractor-beautiful-reporter": "^1.3.6",
    "protractor-console-plugin": "^0.1.1",
    "protractor-istanbul-plugin": "2.0.0",
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.5.0",
    "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "testrail-api": "^1.3.6",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "yargs-parser": "^18.1.2",
    "minimist": "1.2.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "startSE": "node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start",
    "setup": "npm install && node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver-manager-update": "node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver-manager-start": "node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start --versions.standalone=3.141.59",
    "version": "protractor --version"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

---

Tried the solution on this question [Protractor / Typescript (es6): SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61151108/protractor-typescript-es6-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside) but no luck.

Comment: Do ypu want to use type script or normal javascript is enough ?

Comment: could you add your package .json also

Comment: "type": "module", try adding this to your package.json

Comment: @PDHide yes I've already tried adding type, but same result. See updates. Thank you!

Comment: shot in the dark - why do you import `Config` within your config file? isn't it creates a loop or something?

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov I think you have a point. I see this question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56252999/failed-loading-config-ts-due-to-import-protractor

And 1 answer says, "you can't give Protractor a config file in native Typescript, and need to compile it to config.js then pass that"

Comment: So I think I might need to convert it back to js instead.

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov I based the code here.

https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/5.4.1/exampleTypescript#protractor-typings

import {Config} from 'protractor';

export let config: Config = {
  ...
}